# Нужно "вытянуть" из данной строки конкретный адрес сайта

Tags: linux, xml, bash, xpath

Мне вздумалось сделать скрипт, который будет раз в неделю заходить на сайт doomguy.ru и скачивать оттуда свежий мод. Я догадался в скрипте сначала скопировать текст страницы с модами в файл, из этого файла выявить одну строку с адресом странички мода. Проблема в том, что сам адрес, допустим https://doomguy.ru/50-monsters-doom2-megawad.html смешан с еще кучей всего в той же строке:

```
<a class="feature-img" href="***https://doomguy.ru/50-monsters-doom2-megawad.html***" rel="bookmark" title="Перейти к записи Бодрый мегавад 50 Monsters для Doom II Маленький проект, но с большой душой"><img width="1190" height="897"   alt="50 monsters" loading="lazy" data-srcset="https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters.jpg 1190w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-400x302.jpg 400w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-1024x772.jpg 1024w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-768x579.jpg 768w"  data-src="https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters.jpg" data-sizes="(max-width: 1190px) 100vw, 1190px" class="attachment-retro-featured-large size-retro-featured-large wp-post-image lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" /><noscript><img width="1190" height="897" src="https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters.jpg" class="attachment-retro-featured-large size-retro-featured-large wp-post-image" alt="50 monsters" loading="lazy" srcset="https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters.jpg 1190w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-400x302.jpg 400w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-1024x772.jpg 1024w, https://doomguy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/50-monsters-768x579.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1190px) 100vw, 1190px" /></noscript></a>
```

Нужно каким-то образом из этой строки достать этот самый адрес, чтобы далее перейти по нему и скачать то, что нужно. Я пробовал утилитой cut, но либо плохо пробовал, либо она не подходит.

Comment: `xmllint` и другие подобные программы, которые сумеют работать с XPath.

Comment: `wget https://doomguy.ru/doom-mods; xmllint --nowarning --html --xpath '//a[@class="feature-img"]/@href' doom-mods 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's,[[:space:]]\+href="\(.*\)",\1,'` Но лучше, конечно, делать это на Питоне или подобных языках программирования.

Comment: Ну и по теме, почему там `sed`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192620/how-to-get-all-attributes-with-same-tag-name-with-xmllint-xpath (Если нужна только первая ссылка из списка, то `string()` вокруг XPath как раз это сделает и `sed` будет не нужен)

Answer (score 1):

Как реализовать с помощью средств или команд linux я не знаю, но одним из вариантов могу посоветовать это сделать с помощью ЯП python, и использованием библиотеки bs4.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '' # ваша ссылка
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
something = # здесь нужно будет дописать некоторый код, для поиска того html, который вы привели
soup.select_one(something).get('href')`
```

Как альтернативный вариант - можете записать эту ссылку в текстовый файл, и потом сможете считать его средствами linux:)

Comment: Вы бы написали, что поиск осуществляется на языке XPath. И это как правило однострочник.

Comment: @0andriy, насколько мне известно, beatifulsoup не поддерживает Xpath.

Comment: Почему же? Он вроде бы умеет в качестве парсека использовать ElementTree.

Comment: @0andriy,  если только подключать, как вы указали дополнительную библиотеку)

Answer (score -1):

Вот эта команда

```
egrep -o 'https://doomguy.ru/.*.html'
```

Выведет ссылку, которая тебе нужна. Далее её можно передать в wget или curl с помощью xargs

Comment: О, нет! Не надо использовать регулярные выражения против XML.

Comment: После передачи файла этой команде она очень долго думала, или ждала ввода, но ничего не выводила. Я решил, что файл слишком большой, перенес строку с адресом в отдельный файл, запустил команду из него, но результат тот-же, то-есть никакой.

Comment: @0andriy, Почему?

Comment: @RavenUno вот здесь «разжёвано»: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2511795

Answer (score -1):

[getlinks](https://gist.github.com/davemac/1eb4b231ab498e2e031bb2b8345a5df1#file-getlinks)

get from a remote file to STDOUT:

wget -qO- https://www.membrane-australasia.org/gallery/imstec-2016-adelaide-part-3/ |
grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | grep -Eo 'href="[^"]+"' |
grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*' |
uniq

get from a remote file to xargs and download each URL

wget -qO- https://www.membrane-australasia.org/gallery/imstec-2016-adelaide-part-1/ | grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | grep -Eo 'href="[^"]+"' | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*' | uniq | xargs -n 1 -P 24 curl -LO

local file version:

grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' file.htm | grep -Eo 'href="[^"]+"' | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*' | uniq

[How to use grep and cut in script to obtain website URLs from an HTML file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181254/how-to-use-grep-and-cut-in-script-to-obtain-website-urls-from-an-html-file)

Ну просто поискать: Как использовать grep и cut в скрипте для получения URL сайта из файла HTML

Comment: Не стоит. Почитайте комментарий выше в рассуждениях, почему регулярные выражения против XML — это очень плохая практика.

Comment: Я просто предоставил человеку информацию на конкретно поставленный вопрос https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181254/how-to-use-grep-and-cut-in-script-to-obtain-website-urls-from-an-html-file. Ясно, что он находится в начале пути. Рассуждения о плохой и хорошей практике мне понятны. Вопрос только один - сможет ли на данном этапе Maxim Timakov реализовать хорошие практики?

Comment: Извиняюсь! Вопрошающий Raven Uno

Comment: Infrastructure Library (ITIL):
"Adhering to ITIL principles helps ensure you can get to the root cause of problems in your environment as quickly as possible and that you have the right visibility into the systems and people to prevent future problems."

Comment: Я добавил новый комментарий к посту, показывающий, как это сделать в shell.

Comment: (И когда хотите, чтобы ваш коментарий был заметен, обращайтесь по нику так: `@nickname`)